# Hibernate: Inheritance Mapping to Legacy-Database

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm having a few problems trying to map our Legacy Oracle-Database to Hibernate. More specifically, I can't get a correct Inheritance-Mapping to work. The example I've been working with is a Person-Employee-Relationship. In our database the tables are seperate so the only Mapping-Strategy would be Joined. Now the problem is that the PK of Employee consists of EmployeeId and and CompanyId with PersonId being just a normal FK. And there is no way to change that without screwing up the currently running system.
Here is the current code for Person and Employee:

Person.class

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "personas")
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    private String personId;
    private boolean physical;
    private String name;
    private String fantasyName;
    private char gender;

    @Id
    @Column (name = "cod_persona")
    public String getPersonId() {
        return personId;
}

    public void setPersonId(String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    //rest of setters and getters
}
```

Employee.class:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "rh_empleados")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (name = "cod_persona")
public class Employee extends Person {
    private Company company;
    private String employeeId;
    private Integer finalSalary;
    private Branch branch;

    @Basic (optional = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "cod_empresa")
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @Basic (optional = false)
    @Column (name = "cod_empleado")
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
}

    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    //rest of setters and getters
}
```

What already works: creating or deleting a new employee or person
What doesn't works: selecting already existing employees or people, I don't get an exception or something just doesn't return anything.

It has to have something to do with the inheritance because with another entity that is not in a inheritance hierarchy it works perfectly.

Any tips/ideas/workarounds or am I screwed?
Everthing would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Apparently creating or deleting an employee now doesn't work either which kinda makes more sense. I get a "Fail to convert to internal representation".

Comment: Does nobody have an idea? Or could at least tell me for sure that it is definitely not going to work? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an annoying problem!

One solution is to not model the Employee-Person relationship as inheritance. The difference in their primary keys argues against that.

Instead, you could model it as composition, where an Employee [has a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) person. If you want to be able to deal with Employees and People more uniformly, then you could define an interface like:

```
public interface Individual {
    public Person self();
}
```

With implementations by Person:

```
    public Person self() {
        return this;
    }
```

And Employee:

```
    public Person self() {
        return person;
    }
```

Although this would be a bit weird.

Comment: Yeah sure something like an interface or onetoone-relationship would be possible, i already tried around with that but a functioning inheritance would be so much easier. The database is already pretty much a mess and I would really prefer to keep it as simple as possible. Maybe someone else has an idea?

Comment: I hope so. I initially wrote that what you wanted wasn't possible, but the documentation for `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` sort of suggests that it is. I would be as interested as you to see a proper solution!